# Parsing an array of long using jackson

Tags: spring, http, jackson

I am getting the following error while calling my http method.(Spring boot application)

> "JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of
>   java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token".

Its a DELETE call and I am passing my JSON as given below

```
{
    "locationIds": [
      45,
        121,
        89
    ]
}
```

and in my controller side I am using below snippet as my request body.

```
@RequestBody List<Long> locationIDList
```

Comment: try naming locationIdList into locationIds

Comment: or try to create custom type (LongListDto) where you explicitly map List of long to the location you need. I think mapping is the problem.

Comment: Thank you Sarief. Used wrapper object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting an Object with an array property, not an array. So you should have a Java class *LocationIdListDto.java* with a property *locationIds*, then it would work.

Finally a recommendation. You should never post, or return arrays directly from JSON, always wrap them in an object (like you do here). The reason I recommend this, is that one of the most common mutation of an API is to add another property at the outer level. This is no possible if the outer most structure isn an array, which means you either break backwards compatibility, or you have to create a new endpoint method for the new JSON.